# Google Maps API JS Error: Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting this error if i'm trying to get the map for 2 destinations. For example Toronto ^ Montreal. What should i do?

Refused to display 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key= [MY_KEY] ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

But if i'm trying to take url and call it, it gives me json params.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this. Generated a new api for a new project and it works fine.